# css modified select arrow - font-awesome wont load

Tags: css, font-awesome

I want to edit a select-box but the arrow wont change I did include font-awesome in my page.

### CSS

```
#editDocent{
    background-color: white;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance:  none;
}

#editDocent:after{
    content: "\f063";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

### HTML & PHP

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/font-awesome.min.css">

<select id="editDocent">
    <?php
    $docentenQuery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE is_docent = '1'");
    $docentenNumRows = mysqli_num_rows($docentenQuery);
    $docentenResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($docentenQuery);

    foreach ($docentenQuery as $data) {
        if ($data['id'] == $result2['id']) {
            echo "<option data-id='" . $data['id'] . "' selected>" . $data["voornaam"] . " " . $data["achternaam"] . "</option>";
        } else {
            echo "<option data-id='" . $data['id'] . "'>" . $data["voornaam"] . " " . $data["achternaam"] . "</option>";
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Please add your html too.

Comment: Did you set the @font-face with ``font-family: FontAwesome`` in your CSS as stated here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp ?

Comment: @j3ff I just added it, but still doesnt do anything

Comment: @Lenap I guess it must be an html concern .. plz post your related html.

Comment: @j3ff made an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use before and after on html select elements, that's how it is!

```
#editDocent{
    background-color: white;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance:  none;
}

#editDocent:after{
    content: "\f063";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

```
<div id="editDocent">
    <select>
    <?php
    $docentenQuery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE is_docent = '1'");
    $docentenNumRows = mysqli_num_rows($docentenQuery);
    $docentenResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($docentenQuery);

    foreach ($docentenQuery as $data) {
        if ($data['id'] == $result2['id']) {
            echo "<option data-id='" . $data['id'] . "' selected>" . $data["voornaam"] . " " . $data["achternaam"] . "</option>";
        } else {
            echo "<option data-id='" . $data['id'] . "'>" . $data["voornaam"] . " " . $data["achternaam"] . "</option>";
        }
    }
    ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have a alternative?

Comment: You can get around with it if you wrap your select element and do the before or after on the wrapper

Comment: Sorry to say, do you have any example? Not realy clear to me what you mean

Comment: np mate, happy you got it :)